# Where to write custom lib functions in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress, I would like to know where to write custom lib functions in wordpress ?

This there a particular file I should be adding it too, or in a particular manner ?

e.g. get_latest_news() a function like this will be used in many of my widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you open your themes functions.php file 
you can include your custom functions in that,

or use

```
include('custom-functions.php');
```

this will load the file and keep it seperate from your standard wordpress functions.